# Excluding data from a queried table after sql join

Tags: sql, mariadb

I don't know if i am not thinking about the correct join structure but i can't seem to get the results that I want from this join.

This is my sql schema for these 3 tables

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dFaS.png)

```
select target, sender, message, amount, transactiontime, transaction_id 
from transactions 
join accounts on transactions.sender=accounts.account_id 
join users on users.user_id=accounts.user_id 
where users.user_id=40 
union 
select target, sender, message, amount, transactiontime, transaction_id 
from transactions 
join accounts on transactions.target=accounts.account_id 
join users on users.user_id=accounts.user_id
where users.user_id=40 
order by transactiontime 
limit 20;
```

[SQL result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrIoI.png)

This is the query that i have and it queries through 3 tables. Basically I only want the information from just my transaction table but I want to exclude any account_id not associated to that user. In this case the user id is 40 and their account_id is 57. Was wondering how I would be able to get rid of that. Basically how to get the 3 to not show up. Also as a bonus, what would the structure of the query for including id's associated to my accounts. Like if account_id 4 and 57 belonged to one user and money was flowing between them. How would I be able to see both the 4 and 57 in my transaction query table?

Comment: I don't get it. You are showing the first 20 transactions of user 40, no matter via which of their accounts and no matter whether as sender or receiver. Is this not what you want? What else do you want? It might help if you showed us results you get vs. results you expect (and as text please not as an image link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "**exclude** any account_id **not** associated to that user",
Does that not mean "Include only accounts associated to that user"?

```
declare @user_id int = 40

select target, sender, message, amount, transactiontime, transaction_id 
from transactions 
join accounts   on  transactions.sender=accounts.account_id 
                OR  transactions.target=accounts.account_id 
where accounts.user_id=@user_id
```

If the goal is to only see transaction of accounts that both (sender and target) belong to the same user:

```
declare @user_id int = 40

select target, sender, message, amount, transactiontime, transaction_id 
from transactions 
join accounts  as send on  transactions.sender=send.account_id 
join accounts  as targ on  transactions.target=targ.account_id 
where send.user_id=@user_id 
and   targ.user_id=@user_id
```

Comment: Yes so I would not want any accounts that don't belong to that user, also this query would still show the account_id information for the other user

Comment: This query gets you the transactions of which the accounts belonging to the user were either a sender or a target. It is possible, or probable, that another user's account is the sender/target counterpart in any given transaction.

Comment: Is the goal to only get transaction between accounts that both belong to the same user? (edited answer)

Comment: The conditional join was what i needed actually! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the information from your transaction table for a given user id:

```
select 
    *
from 
    transactions
where 
    transactions.user_id = 40
```

should be enough. You don't need the `union` statement to the same query again or to join to the user table.

If you want to list all of the account ids for the people these transactions are going to, you can use:

```
select 
    target, sender, message, amount, transactiontime, transactions.transaction_id, accounts.account_id
from 
    transactions
inner join
    accounts
on
    transactions.target = accounts.user_id
```